# Rep not synchronized

Tags: bug, support, status-bydesign, reputation

I was under the impression that rep was synchronized across a parent site and its corresponding meta site. I'm getting a 30 point difference when I switch back and forth between bicycles and meta.bicycles. Is anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation is synchronized, but not immediately.

It can take up to an hour for the two sites to sync up, so if you're gaining rep pretty regularly on the parent its not unusual for your meta rep to be slightly out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to sync immediately, log out of the parent site, then log back in. But other than that, sync is hourly.

Comment: I notice that I have different badges on the two sites.  Are they synced as well?

Comment: @geoffc: No, badges are *specific* to the parent and meta site. Separate to each.